# A show about four heroes fighting against evil

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for a show I watched about 10 years ago. I don't remember much from that show, but I hope it will suffice.

The show has a medieval setting. The four protagonists have each a specific weapon and some elemental powers. I only remember three of the weapons and respective elemental powers.

- Trident -> Water
- Morning star -> Earth
- Crossbow -> Wind

The crossbow user is a woman while the other three are men. What I remember from the story is, that each of them had to go on a quest to get stronger powers or better transformation equipment or so I suppose.

I hope these information are enough. If additional information is needed, I'll try to add them to the question.

**Edit:**
The language I watched it in was german. It was a Live Action show.

Comment: Can you confirm language please.  Also, animated or live action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165588/combined) from 1998. From Wiki:

> Queen Maeve of Temra, to conquer the peaceful kingdom of Kells, enlists the fairy Mider, who gives her the mystical Rune Stone allowing Maeve to use sorcery, most often to create ogres and evil giants, whom she sends to wreak havoc. When King Conchobar of Kells seeks a way to protect his kingdom, protagonist Rohan, a druid's apprentice, goes in search of the prophesized hero 'Draganta', with his friend the reformed thief Angus. Later joined by the foreign Prince Ivar, and Conchobar's daughter, Princess Deirdre, they are drawn into Tir Na Nóg, whose king Fin Varra puts the group through various tests to determine their worthiness. **The heroes having passed these tests, King Fin Varra gives them certain weapons granting control of the Classical Elements Fire, Air, Earth, and Water.**

Deirdre's weapon was the Whirlwind Crossbow; Ivan's weapon was a trident. Here's how it opened:

Comment: What an epic looking show. The dragon at the end makes it :)